# How to enlarge hat?

Tags: support, profile-picture, winter-bash

I see some users can enlarge their hats to the biggest size, and it entirely fills out their avatars. How do I do this? My only option is to moving it around, but I cannot make it large as I wish.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a 'Show Controls' dialog to move around and resize your hat:

[image: show controls]

This lets you enlarge, make smaller, rotate and move about the hat to however you want!

Specifically to enlarge the hat, you can click and drag the red button away or towards the centre of the red and blue lines, moving it in a circular motion around the centre, however, rotates the hat.